# Как сделать Apk на React Native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Как сделать Apk из проекта? Использую Expo. Нет папок Android, ios.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так:

**Build a standalone APK for your project, signed and ready for submission to the Google Play Store.**

```
exp build:android|ba [options] [project-dir]
```

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/workflow/expo-cli

Comment: щас можно через AndroidStudio делать. если так делать весит почти 2 раза меньше.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

**Вводишь команду с консоли в папке проекта**
`expo build:android`